Probability of People Leaving a Cocktail Party
As a brain teaser, I am trying to write mathematical equations (e.g. a stochastic process) corresponding to the following situation:

Suppose there is a cocktail that starts with $n$ people. After some
random time $t$, the first person leaves. With each additional person
leaving, the rate of the next departure increases (assume no new people can enter the party and no people can come back). Suppose we define
such a stochastic process, Can we find out the probability that $k$
people will leave in the next $j$ minutes? Can we find out the expected amount of time needed for $k$ people to leave in $j$ minutes?

Here is my attempt to do this.
First, we define:
$$ n : \text{initial number of people at the party} $$
$$ X_t : \text{number of people remaining at the party at time } t $$
$$ \lambda_t : \text{rate at which people leave at time } t $$
Now, the basic process:
$$ X_0 = n $$
$$ P(X_{t+1} = k | X_t = k) = e^{-\lambda_t} \quad \text{for } k < n $$
$$ P(X_{t+1} = k-1 | X_t = k) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_t} \quad \text{for } k \leq n $$
To model the increasing probability of leaving as more people depart, we need to define $\lambda_t$ accordingly (i.e. choose some function which obeys this property):
$$ \lambda_t = \alpha \cdot \frac{n - X_t + 1}{X_t} $$
$$ \alpha : \text{base rate parameter (} \alpha > 0 \text{)} $$
Based on the derivatives and the limits, we can see that if this function is chosen, the rate at which people leave increases as more people leave:
$$ \frac{d\lambda_t}{dX_t} = \alpha \cdot \frac{-(n+1)}{(X_t)^2} $$
$$ \lim_{X_t \to 0^+} \lambda_t = \lim_{X_t \to 0^+} \alpha \cdot \frac{n - X_t + 1}{X_t} = +\infty $$
From here, I assumed discrete time (i.e. departures can only happen at fixed times) to simplify the problem.

1) Discrete time : A maximum of one person can leave at each time point
Define:
$$ n : \text{initial number of people at the party} $$
$$ X_t : \text{number of people remaining at the party at time } t $$
$$ P_k(j) : \text{probability that exactly } k \text{ people leave in the next } j \text{ time steps} $$
$$ p_t(1) : \text{probability of a single person leaving at time step } t $$
At each time step, we have:
$$ p_t(1) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_t} = 1 - e^{-\alpha \cdot \frac{n - X_t + 1}{X_t}} $$
Consider what can happen in the last (j-th) time step:
$$ \text{Either one person leaves (with probability } p_j(1) \text{) or no one leaves (with probability } 1-p_j(1) \text{)} $$
If one person leaves in the j-th step, then k-1 people must have left in the previous j-1 steps:
$$ P_{k-1}(j-1) \cdot p_j(1) $$
If no one leaves in the $j^{th}$ step, then all $k$ people must have left in the previous $j-1$ steps:
$$ P_k(j-1) \cdot (1-p_j(1)) $$
The total probability is the sum of these two mutually exclusive events:
$$ P_k(j) = P_{k-1}(j-1) \cdot p_j(1) + P_k(j-1) \cdot (1-p_j(1)) $$
Recursively, we can write:
$$ P_{k-1}(j-1) = P_{k-2}(j-2) \cdot p_{j-1}(1) + P_{k-1}(j-2) \cdot (1-p_{j-1}(1)) $$
As a formality, some initial conditions are likely need for logical reasons:

The probability of $0$ people leaving is $1$, and the probability of any number of people leaving is $0$. That is, when $j = 0$ (no time has passed):
$$ P_0(0) = 1 $$
$$ P_k(0) = 0 \text{ for } k > 0 $$

In one time step: When $j = 1$ (only one time step):
$$ P_0(1) = 1 - p_1(1) $$
$$ P_1(1) = p_1(1) $$
$$ P_k(1) = 0 \text{ for } k > 1 $$



Expected Time
To find the expected amount of time needed for $k$ people to leave in $j$ minutes, let's define:
$$ T_k : \text{random variable representing the time needed for k people to leave} $$
Now, we want to calculate:
$$ E[T_k | T_k \leq j] $$
This is the expected value of $T_k$ given that it occurs within j minutes. To calculate this, I think we can use the concept of conditional expectation:
$$ E[T_k | T_k \leq j] = \frac{\int_0^j t \cdot f_{T_k}(t) dt}{P(T_k \leq j)} $$
Where $f_{T_k}(t)$ is the probability density function of $T_k$.
In the discrete time, this becomes:
$$ E[T_k | T_k \leq j] = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^j t \cdot P(T_k = t)}{P(T_k \leq j)} $$
Now, we need to calculate $P(T_k = t)$ and $P(T_k \leq j)$.

$P(T_k = t)$: The probability that exactly $k$ people leave at time $t$.

$P(T_k \leq j)$: The probability that $k$ or more people have left by time $j$.


For $P(T_k = t)$:
For $T_k = t$ to be true, we need:

Exactly $k-1$ people to have left by time $t-1$
The $k$-th person to leave at exactly time $t$

We can express this as:
$$ P(T_k = t) = P_{k-1}(t-1) \cdot p_t(1) $$
This is because:

$P_{k-1}(t-1)$ is the probability that exactly $k-1$ people have left by time $t-1$
$p_t(1)$ is the probability that one more person leaves at time $t$

For $P(T_k \leq j)$:
This is the probability that $k$ or more people have left by time $j$. In our model, this is equivalent to the probability that exactly $k$ people have left by time $j$, because we stop counting once $k$ people have left. Therefore:
$$ P(T_k \leq j) = P_k(j) $$
We can calculate this directly using the earlier recursive formula:
$$ P_k(j) = P_{k-1}(j-1) \cdot p_j(1) + P_k(j-1) \cdot (1-p_j(1)) $$

Conclusion: I am mentally exhausted after all these manipulations. Originally, I had wanted to find out the distribution for "$k$ people leaving in $j$ minutes" and the distribution of the "expected amount of time needed for $k$ people to leave in $j$ minutes", but I will save this for a later question (I think its easier to simulate). I also wanted to attempt this question in continuous time, but there is no way I have the courage for this right now.
But concerning the limited work I have done in discrete time - does my work make sense?
Cheers


PS: A naive simulation



This is a pure death process. Extensively studied, so you will be able to find plenty of references online.

Thank you for reaching out! Such a depressing name "pure death process" lol! I prefer the "cocktail party" ... sounds a bit more cheerful lol!

@Snoop: do you have any comments about my analysis/logic ?

This follows a phase type distribution. For specific cases you can derive more precise special cases. For example if the rate is increasing with $\lambda_t = 1/(n-X_t)$, then $X_t$ can be related to an order statistic.

Is there any logic/mechanism behind $$\lambda_t = \alpha \cdot \frac{n - X_t + 1}{X_t}?$$ That could help to understand/visualize the problem.

thnk you sextus for suggesting phase type distribution. I found myself a bit lost trying to develop a model to describe this  .... could you please write an answer for this if you have time?

The solution to
$$
\frac{d\lambda_t}{d X_t}=-\alpha(n+1)\frac{1}{X_t^2}
$$
for constant $\alpha(n+1)$ is
$$
d\lambda_t=-\alpha(n+1)\frac{1}{X_t^2} dX_t
$$
$$
\lambda_t-\lambda_0=\alpha(n+1)[\frac{1}{X_t}-\frac{1}{X_0}]
$$

A physicist's approach.
I think that social phenomena are too complex to construct precise mathematical models.That is why I proceed from the most general assumption in setting up the formulated task:
With each additional person leaving, the rate of the next departure increases (assume no new people can enter the party and no people can come back).
So I'm looking at the simplest model based on that:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}n }{\mathrm{d} t}=-\frac{k}{n^a}$$
where
$$0<k,a $$
and $n$ is the number of people at the moment $t$ and for the sake of simplicity, we take $n$ as a continuous variable.
The solution of this simple differential equation considering that at the beginning moment $t=0$ we have $n=n_{0}$ people is
$$n(t)=\left [n_{0}^{a+1}-(a+1)kt  \right ]^{\frac{1}{a+1}}$$
The party ends at the moment $t=T$ when the last person leaves i.e. $n(T)=0$:
$$T=\frac{n_{0}^{a+1}}{(a+1)k}$$
In other words, the most general form:
$$T=b\times  n_{0}^{\gamma}$$
Of course, the most pleasant part here is that the empirical constants $0< b$ and $1< \gamma$ must be determined by visiting at least two different cocktail parties from start to finish.
